# How do I query part of a word using couchdb-lucene?

Tags: jquery, search, lucene, request, couchdb

For example, I'm searching for user "John Doe" but wish to type just "John" or "Doe" in order to get the user.

This is the request i'm making at the moment:

```
request('http://' + globals.serverAddress + ':' + globals.lucenePort + '/_fti/local/testdatabase/_design/lucene/by_user_name?q=' + req.query.searchString + '&include_docs=true', function(error, requestResponse, body) {

// Sending the data here from the API to the app

});
```

At the moment, I am able to search "John Doe" and get the user, but cannot use parts of the word to find the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your index "by_user_name"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view and emit every word o f the text by it self along to a reference like de id of the doc.

This will create a huge view to which you can query

Im guessing you  emit a field called user_name on the design /_design/lucene/by_user_name , instead of that try using a for and a split. emit via a for cycle, every element of the array that splitting by a space(" ") will generate, and that's it